# Login Register and Search on same page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms

I want to do my login, register and search on the same paged on my website. I am making the website  using ASP.NET. Clearly, more than one forms cannot be done on the same page for ASP.NET. So, what is the solution for this? Should I do nested master-page? Or is there any other way to have multiple forms? Or any other alternative to add contents?

Comment: you can use jquery ajax for submitting these multiple functionalities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my own question. At first there were three form tags for three forms. Then I added one **runat** server form wrapping all the three. The problem here was only the first form was acting. So, I replaced the three form tags inside with three div tags. Now it works fine! :)

This is Because ASP.Net Web Form can have **only one runat="Server" Form tag**.